# how to get the memory size occupied by a image programatically in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

i want to print how much memory is occupying by a image when that particular image is loaded. can anyone have idea?
Please help me
 Thank You
Lakshmi

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`UIImage` provides no obvious way of telling the memory of the underlying data. However we could use Core Graphics to give us the estimate. You could probably get an estimate of the memory occupied by an image by doing

```
size_t imageSize = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image.CGImage) * CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
```

But I suggest you don't base any image management on this. You really don't know how much memory you will have with you. Try to minimize how many images you've loaded into memory. Basically, optimize as necessary.

Comment: How to optimize the image which I'm loading

Comment: `size_t` is an `unsigned long` so use `%lu`. I suggest reading [`this`](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html) for information on images. When I was talking of optimizing I was talking of image management and not images. But I would expect you would make sure that image is specific in size. Don't take a high-res image for a small image view. If you are dealing with zooming images that need to be high resolution, you can look at `CAScrollLayer`s too. If you don't need an image often, don't use `imageNamed:` as it caches the images.

Comment: XCode tells me to do the following to print it:     NSLog(@"%zu",imageSize);