# iOS get UIImage memory size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I want to get UIImage Object real memory size.
There are 3 methods

```
NSUInteger s1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbImage).length;
NSUInteger s2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbImage, 1).length;
NSUInteger s3  = CGImageGetHeight(thumbImage.CGImage) * CGImageGetBytesPerRow(thumbImage.CGImage);
NSLog(@"s1:%u",s1);
NSLog(@"s2:%u",s2);
NSLog(@"s3:%u",s3);
```

and result

s1:62734

s2:175939

s3:578816

which one is right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402614/how-to-get-the-memory-size-occupied-by-a-image-programatically-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last one (s3) is correct:

- s1 is the size of a .png image when saved to a file
- s2 is the size of a .jpg image when save to a file with best quality

Comment: but why jpg size bigger than png size when saved to a file,It should be opposite in normal.

Comment: You can trade jpg file size for image quality. The `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` `compressionQuality` parameter determines the amount of compression, and can range from 0 to 1. In the code example the jpg representation has a quality setting of 1, or maximum quality, which will result in the largest jpg file. PNG is a lossless compression, and depending on the image, may yield a smaller file size than a "high quality" jpg file.

Comment: @bobnoble why are memory and disk sizes different?

Comment: @onmyway133 Size in memory is based on the size (width and height) and depth (bytes per pixel) of the photo. In-memory photos are not compressed as jpeg or png photos are on disk.