# How to get date and filesize from a picture?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, nsdata, nsfilemanager

If pictures are loaded into an app from a album, how is it possible to get the filesize in MB and the date of that picture displayed on a app like on the screenshot below?

[image]

I know you can retrieve the filesize via a NSLog using the following code, but how can I get this into a string and also the date of that picture?

```
NSLog(@"size of image in KB: %i",[UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage) length]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CoreGraphics

```
size_t imageSize = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image.CGImage) * CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
```

[iOS get UIImage memory size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483931/ios-get-uiimage-memory-size)